# Record video as in vine app on touch

Tags: xcode

I am working on a video app. I want to record video as in vine app. Means record on tap and stop record on remove tap.
Please tell me how to add frame on touches.

Answer (score 5):

I put together something that could be useful for you. https://github.com/Kseniya/NewVideoRecorder

Using AVCaptureSession record while holding your finger, stop when release. Hold again, record a next one. Add them into an array. And then at the end merge them into one composition and save into camera roll.

I'm still working on it, so i'll be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is working fine. I tested the app. I think it is not merging video correctly in iOS7.

Comment: What exactly happening with merging in iOS7? i didn't notice anything. let me know and i'll fix it.

Comment: Showing black screen between videos

Comment: Tested on iphone 5s and iphone 4s both with ios 7 and not seeing this issue. What device do you see this problem on?

Comment: @Kseniya video has not captured correctly while using front cam. It is displaying like small rectangle box at the top corner. Now i am working on similar to this.